# /dev/tty not available from autosys

Tags: shell, autosys

A simple shell script to echo into the /dev/tty file:

```
$ cat a.sh
#/bin/bash

echo welcome >/dev/tty
```

Everything goes fine. Now, when the same shell script is executed from autosys, it is giving an error:

```
/dev/tty: cannot create [No such device or address]
```

Not clear why from autosys, the tty file is not available. Can anybody help in understanding  why this happens?

Comment: Guessing it doesn't use a tty as it is a job sheduler? Where are you expecting the echo to go?

Comment: @123 : Not expecting it to go anywhere. The thing is this buggy code was failing from autosys, so we are not sure what was causing the failure. I just put a sample snippet, not the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/dev/tty` entry points to the current *terminal*.

When you run a job from autosys there is no terminal associated with the job, and so attempts to access `/dev/tty` will result in an error.  You'll see the same thing if you use `cron` or `at` or other schedulers.

Normally only interactive processes would try and use `/dev/tty`.

With autosys, the system will catch *STDOUT* (normal output) and *STDERR* (error messages) and put them into the job result data, which you can then retrieve and review.

If you wish to write output that goes elsewhere... where should it go?  There's no terminal.  You might want to try `/dev/console` but that requires root acess.  You might want a log file, or use `syslog`.  But, normally, you'd just let autosys collect STDOUT/STDERR as normal :-)